# Nginx Remove Trailing Question Mark From URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule in Nginx to remove trialing question mark (`?`) from urls but i can't get it right. I've done that for trailing slashes like this:

```
#redirect all trailing slash URL's to the respective non trailing slash
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

so I figured the same would work just replacing the slash with the question mark:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)?$ /$1 permanent;
```

but that didn't work, but it occurred to me that the question mark has some significance in the regex so i tried escaping it:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)\?$ /$1 permanent;
```

but that didn't work either, I tried also removing the first slash:

```
rewrite ^(.*)\?$ $1 permanent;
```

but that was also a bust, and yes i did restart the server in between tests.

Here's what I am trying to do:

- `www.mysite.com?` should redirect to `wwww.mysite.com`
- `www.mysite.com/some/path?` should redirect to `wwww.mysite.com/some/path`
- `www.mysite.com?some=vars` should remain unchanged.
- `www.mysite.com/some/path?some=vars` should remain unchanged.

so basically only removing the question mark if there is no query string. 
How can i accomplish that?

I've checked other answers but they seem to want to remove the query string entirely, I only want to remove in the case that there is only a question mark and no parameters.

Comment: I have answered your question over on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058106/nginx-remove-trailing-question-mark/54066446#54066446)

Answer (score 1):

Richard Smith gave me the answer on SO, i'll leave the answer here also in case someone ends up on this one:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)\?$) { return 301 $1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if ($is_args) {
    if ($args = "") {
        return 301 $uri;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, so I am not sure if this will work. It all depends on what value nginx sets to `$is_args` when there is only the question mark in the URL and not any arguments.

Comment: that didn't work, the following url `https://www.example.com/some/path?some=var` ended up becoming `https://www.example.com/some/httpswww.example.com/some/path`

Comment: Please try my updated answer.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen if statements cannot be nested.